# Why do I get an EntryPointNotFoundException error when using .NET 6.0, but not when using 4.7.1?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, interop, .net-6.0

I am creating a DLL using C++ and importing it using C#. I have no problem compiling the DLL, and it works fine when calling it from .NET 4.7.1. However, when I try to call it from .NET 6.0, I get an `EntryPointNotFoundException` error:

```
Unhandled exception. System.EntryPointNotFoundException: 
Unable to find an entry point named 'E' in DLL 'test.dll'.
   at Program.E(int a, int b)
   at Program.Main(String[] args) in G:\C++\Test\Program.cs:line 6
```

#### *Test.csproj*

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <!--<TargetFramework>net4.7.1</TargetFramework>-->
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

#### *Test.cpp*

```cpp
extern "C"__declspec(dllexport) int E(int a, int b)
{
   return x + y;
}
```

#### *Program.cs*

```cs
public class Program
{
    [DllImport("test.dll")] public static extern int E(int a, int b);
    public static void Main(string [] args)
    {
        float r = E(11, 26);
        System.Console.WriteLine(r);
    }
}
```

My compiler flags are as follows:

```
g++ -shared -o test.dll Test.cpp -Wl,--out-implib,test.dll
```

**Research:**

Because it is clear that this is an issue with .NET 6, I performed some specific searches using Google:

- ["Unable to find an entry point named" in DLL ".net 6.0"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Unable%20to%20find%20an%20entry%20point%20named%22%20in%20DLL%20%22.net%206.0%22&client=firefox-b-d&channel=trow5&sxsrf=ALiCzsb0rFWtnUGiFXzK-o7l9IZ8oNNupQ%3A1653445268423&ei=lJKNYtO9GcXDuvQP4sik8AI&ved=0ahUKEwjT14TPy_n3AhXFoY4IHWIkCS4Q4dUDCA0&uact=5&oq=%22Unable%20to%20find%20an%20entry%20point%20named%22%20in%20DLL%20%22.net%206.0%22&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAM6CggjEK4CELADECdKBAhBGAFKBAhGGABQrgRYjCtggy5oBnAAeACAAWGIAbQHkgECMTKYAQCgAQHIAQHAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz) 8 results, 0 valid.
- ["Unable to find an entry point named" in DLL "net6.0"](https://www.google.com/search?channel=trow5&client=firefox-b-d&q=%22Unable%20to%20find%20an%20entry%20point%20named%22%20in%20DLL%20%22net6.0%22) 10 results, 0 valid.
- ["Unable to find an entry point named"  "net6.0"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Unable%20to%20find%20an%20entry%20point%20named%22%20%20%22net6.0%22&client=firefox-b-d&channel=trow5&sxsrf=ALiCzsb0rFWtnUGiFXzK-o7l9IZ8oNNupQ%3A1653445268423&ei=lJKNYtO9GcXDuvQP4sik8AI&ved=0ahUKEwjT14TPy_n3AhXFoY4IHWIkCS4Q4dUDCA0&uact=5&oq=%22Unable%20to%20find%20an%20entry%20point%20named%22%20%20%22net6.0%22&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAM6CggjEK4CELADECdKBAhBGAFKBAhGGABQweMBWNnpAWDs7QFoA3AAeACAAUuIAZYDkgEBNpgBAKABAcgBAcABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz) 47 results, 0 valid.
- ["Unable to find an entry point named"  ".net 6.0"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Unable%20to%20find%20an%20entry%20point%20named%22%20%20%22.net%206.0%22&client=firefox-b-d&channel=trow5&sxsrf=ALiCzsYR1fux6nGSumayuebO25xaDk5otQ%3A1653445426322&ei=MpONYr2oE97BuvQPkcCpiAI&ved=0ahUKEwi9iaqazPn3AhXeoI4IHRFgCiEQ4dUDCA0&uact=5&oq=%22Unable%20to%20find%20an%20entry%20point%20named%22%20%20%22.net%206.0%22&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EANKBAhBGAFKBAhGGABQxa0BWJDDAWDhyAFoBHAAeACAAViIAc4FkgECMTCYAQCgAQHAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz) 9 results, 0 valid.
- ["Unable to find an entry point named"  ".net 6"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Unable%20to%20find%20an%20entry%20point%20named%22%20%20%22.net%206%22&client=firefox-b-d&channel=trow5&sxsrf=ALiCzsZsHws_AEqeXVcQXZtLoOsYJ_9_Gw%3A1653445556250&ei=tJONYprkDsa0uvQPydaRgAk&ved=0ahUKEwiajqTYzPn3AhVGmo4IHUlrBJAQ4dUDCA0&uact=5&oq=%22Unable%20to%20find%20an%20entry%20point%20named%22%20%20%22.net%206%22&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAM6CggjEK4CELADECdKBAhBGAFKBAhGGABQ5g9YlxFgmBhoA3AAeACAAVuIAaYBkgEBMpgBAKABAcgBAcABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz) 1370 results, 0 valid.
- ["Unable to find an entry point named"  " dot net 6"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Unable%20to%20find%20an%20entry%20point%20named%22%20%20%22%20dot%20net%206%22&client=firefox-b-d&channel=trow5&sxsrf=ALiCzsak4JJWAttqxqQz-Rx78qSJN2QboQ%3A1653445604556&ei=5JONYvDJIdvDuvQPzcyykAs&ved=0ahUKEwjwy6jvzPn3AhXboY4IHU2mDLIQ4dUDCA0&uact=5&oq=%22Unable%20to%20find%20an%20entry%20point%20named%22%20%20%22%20dot%20net%206%22&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBwgjELACECc6BwgAEEcQsAM6BwgjEK4CECc6BAgjECdKBAhBGABKBAhGGABQ-sECWIfNAmCuzwJoBHABeACAAVyIAdYDkgEBNpgBAKABAcgBCMABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz) 3 results, 0 valid
- I performed several other variations of the searches, none of which provided any link to .NET 6 and this error.
- I also tried rebooting, using a second computer, and reinstalling .NET 6 on both computers.
- I also looked through the [.NET 6 documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/best-practices), but I could not find a reason this could be happening.

Comment: The question is being discussed on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/418302/11407695).

Comment: And it is not related [to bitness](https://stackoverflow.com/q/270531/270545#270545)? (It can be detected at runtime - *for example*, if 32 bit is required for some reason, the .NET program can test itself and refuse to continue if it is not running as 32 bit (***with*** a \*\*\****meaningful***\*\*\* error message)—not relying on correct external configuration or other external factors to be correct.) For instance, [`IntPtr.Size`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.intptr.size) is 8 if running as 64 bit. [A Stack Overflow lead](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9206483).

Comment: Use procmon from sysinternals and see where both versions are searching.

Comment: Hey Peter, I will have a look today. I ruled out bitness because both 4.7.1 and 6.0 can use both archs and when using the any cpu flags the csproj, results were no different. I will use procmon today though and see what I can find, thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I could reproduce the issue locally with the setup your described using Visual Studio 2022.

**Preliminary note 1:** The naming of all the .NET stuff can be quite confusing: ".NET" is not ".NET Framework". And ".NET Core" is the predecessor of ".NET". Roughly. See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2017/september/net-standard-demystifying-net-core-and-net-standard) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72240581/3740047) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40955459/3740047) post.

**Preliminary note 2:** The main program code in .NET Core and .NET resides in a dll file which needs to be executed using `dotnet myProject.dll`. Starting with .NET Core 3.0, an additional exe file is created which simply wraps that command. On the other hand, .NET Framework produces an exe file directly. Compare e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61112250/3740047) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65947102/3740047) post.

**Your problem:** The issue in your case is now the following: First, you create your `test.dll` via g++. Then you build your `Test.csproj` file which, for .NET 6, produces not only `Test.exe` but also `Test.dll`. Since Windows' file system is case insensitive, building the csproj file **overwrites** your own g++ `test.dll` file. Thus, the resulting `Test.dll` is something entirely different. Attempting to execute `Test.exe` will attempt to import the function `E` from the dll, but since the dll was replaced, the function no longer exists. On the other hand, if you replace the `Test.dll` with the g++ `test.dll` after you built the csproj causes the `Test.exe` to no longer work (because, as described above, `Test.exe` does not really contain your code and instead calls `Test.dll`, which is no longer containing the correct .NET code).

For .NET Framework, on the other hand, the issue does not arise because building the `Test.csproj` file produces only a `Test.exe` and leaves your g++ `test.dll` untouched.

**Solution:** The simplest solution is to name your own dll produced by g++ differently, e.g. `test2.dll`, and import that in the C# project. Or choose a different name for the C# project (or rather, its output).
Another solution would be to publish your .NET 6 project self-contained so that it consists of only an exe file. See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/#publish-self-contained) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44074121/3740047)
or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37390798/3740047) post.

Comment: YES! This is correct and is such a sly problem. Thank you Sedenion, you have truly made my day! I can confirm, that by renaming the dll to something other than that of the csproj file name my dotnet project is in, resolves this issue!!!

Comment: Wow!  That is some insightful intuition!  I totally missed the name-collision from the OP's description.

Comment: Note: Self-contained is not single-file. With .NET 6, you can publish self-contained without creating a single-file distribution, in which case you still have exe+dll.